# PHP files displayed as plain text in browser

Tags: ubuntu, php

I have an ubuntu server installed with apache2 service. but when I run the index.php file its displays as it is. it means .php files are not executing

Comment: Have you looked at this
1. https://serverfault.com/questions/1019602/php-files-displayed-as-text
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512142/php-code-showing-in-browser
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777886/php-code-is-rendered-as-text

Comment: Do you have php installed and Apache set to use it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP files displayed as text](https://serverfault.com/questions/1019602/php-files-displayed-as-text)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have installed php and enabled the apache component. Something like
`a2enmod php7.0` will enable the php processor module for apache if it is installed.

If that does not work, try following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-3-install-php:%7E:text=Step%203%3A%20Install%20PHP,-PHP) tutorial from DigitalOcean, it is quite good explained...

Also check out the [recomendations](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) from the community.

Answer (score -2):

Manually open file in terminal and check for the code. Your file might be saved in rtf or html file, irrespective of ".php" file format.